# How to obtain the cell index selected in UICollectionView

Tags: uicollectionview, swift3, uitableview

I have a uitableview in which a cell contains a UICollectionView. I want to get the index of selected cell within the UICollectionView and I am not able, I tried to search the web but did not work what I found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Result:**

[image]

---

**Storyboard:**

### [image]

**ViewController:**

I have created a closure **didCollectionViewCellSelect** and passing it to **TableViewCell** so that when a cell from **UICollectionView** is done, this closure will be called.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
  }

  lazy var didCollectionViewCellSelect: ((Int) -> Void)? = { (collectionViewCellIndex) in
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail", sender: collectionViewCellIndex)
  }

  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
      if let collectionViewCellIndex = sender as? Int {
        let detailViewController = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
        detailViewController.collectionViewCellIndex = collectionViewCellIndex
      }
    }
  }
}


extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 4
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.didCollectionViewCellSelect = didCollectionViewCellSelect

    return cell
  }
}
```

---

**TableViewCell:**

The important part here is that **TableViewCell** is going to be the delegate for **UICollectionView** as the **delegate** and **dataSource** so that **TableViewCell** will be informed for example when a cell was selected.

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

  @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

  var didCollectionViewCellSelect: ((Int) -> Void)?

  override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code

    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
  }

  override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
  }

}

extension TableViewCell: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 4
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath)

    return cell
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let didCollectionViewCellSelect = didCollectionViewCellSelect {
      didCollectionViewCellSelect(indexPath.row)
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know if you need more explanation about that I did, hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understand your question correctly, you would have the following requirement.

1. You have ViewController which has tableView and inside of your tableViewCell you have CollectionView.
2. So You need to send the event to `ViewController` when the CollectionView's Cell selected.

In your CustomTableViewCell class you would have below CollectionView Delegate method. So there you can call your delegate method which will send the event to your `ViewController`. First add a delegate variable in your CustomTableViewCell like below.

```
protocol CustomCellDelegate {
    func selectedItem(_ item:Int)
}

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell
{
    weak var delegate:CustomCellDelegate?

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
           if delegate != nil
           {
               delegate?.selectedItem?( (indexPath as NSIndexPath).item)
           } 
    }
}
```

In your view controller Just add the CustomCellDelegate

```
class ViewController:UIViewController, CustomCellDelegate{

func selectedItem(_ item:Int){
//Your stuffs
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
          let cell://dequeue your cell here
          cell.delegate = self //This delegate will send the actions from UICollectionView
          return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer Natarajan! but what I need is to call a viewcontroller clicking a cell in a CollectionView